# Неправильное выполнение задач в Cron

Tags: cron

Как запустить одновременно 4 задачи? Сейчас почему-то так:выполняется 1 задание, через 2 минуты другое, через 3 другое. А должны одновременно

```
/usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=1*/1 *   *   *   */usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=2*/1 *   *   *   */usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=3*/1 *   *   *   */usr/bin/php /home/user1781/public_html/monster/test.php ?query=4*/1 *   *   *   *
```

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте...

`*/1 *   *   *   * user echo "Hello world"`

Comment: и что это даст товарищу Артёму?

Comment: Хотя бы то, что у него формат записи отличается.